# NestJS - accepting multiple MIME types in request body

Tags: json, xml, nestjs

I am trying to create an endpoint in a HTTP API that receives data periodically from remote devices.
There is a technological shift happening in this project where devices have previously reported data in XML whereas future implementations will shift towards JSON.

I am writing this API in NestJS (7.x) and TypeScript. Data will be coming in through the same endpoint (`POST /`) and data format is differentiated by the `Content-Type` header.

```js
@Controller()
export class IngressController {
  constructor(private readonly ingressService: IngressService) {
  }

 /* ... */

  @Post('')
  @Header('Cache-Control', 'none')
  @HttpCode(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
  public async receive(
    @Headers('Content-Type') contentType: string,
    @Req() req: any,
    @Body() body: string,
  ): Promise<InsertResponse> {
    if (IngressController.isJson(contentType)) {
      return { inserted: await this.ingressService.insertJsonString(req.body) };
    }
    if (IngressController.isXml(contentType)) {
      return { inserted: await this.ingressService.insertXmlString(req.body) };
    }
    throw new BadRequestException(contentType, 'Unsupported Content-Type');
  }

 /* ... */
}
```

Future devices will report data in JSON (indicated by the `Content-Type: application/json` header in the HTTP request), legacy devices report in XML (`Content-Type: application/xml`).

It works splendidly for JSON. However, my problem is that `req.body` (or `body` respectively) is an empty object in the XML case. I presume the NestJS middleware is doing *something* and getting confused by XML, but I have found no hints as to allow XML payloads side-by-side with JSON. I don't mind parsing it manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you suspected NestJS has a built-in bodyparser that will not be able to parse xml. What you could do is to plug in a custom middleware where you decide whether to parse the request body as xml or pass the request on the the next handler.

Something like this should work (I'm using `express-xml-bodyparser` in this example):

```
import {NestFactory} from '@nestjs/core';
import {AppModule} from './app.module';
import {Request} from "express";

const xmlParser = require('express-xml-bodyparser');
const xmlParserMidleware = xmlParser();

async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    app.use((req: Request, res: any, next: any) => {
        if (req.path.includes("/api/json-or-xml-handler") && req.header('Content-Type')?.includes('xml')) {
            return xmlParserMidleware(req, res, next);
        }
        next();
    });
    await app.listen(8020);
}

bootstrap();
```

Then, in your controller `body` will either be the parsed json-object or an object representation of your xml:

```
@Controller()
export class TestControllerController {
    @Post('/api/json-or-xml-handler')
    receive(@Body() body: any) {
        console.log(body);
        // ...
    }
}
```